# variable average set but not used

Tags: c++

Instructions say

> Write a C++ statement that stores the average of num1, num2, and num3 into average.

Every time I do it, it says variable average set but not used? I am a new programmer and sorry if I ask any very easy obvious questions I am taking this class to see if I like programming. Thank you! This is my first intro to programming class so I am a little bit confused and lost. I've added the int average and set it to equal out the average for the integer average but it still not letting me complete my assignment.

```
//include statement(s)
#include <iostream>
//using namespace statement
using namespace std;

int main()
{

//variable declaration
int average, num1, num2, num3;

num1= 125;
num2= 28;
num3= -25;

average=(num1+num2+num3)/3;

//executable statements


//return 0;
}
```

Please help me out with this problem

Comment: You don't use it anywhere in the posted code either. What platform are you submitting the code on, and is this your full code?

Answer (score 1):

That warning is to be expected if you do not use `average` after its value is set. If the rest of your exercise does not require the use of `average`, then you are doing fine. (Perhaps the exercise should be rewritten, but that is a separate issue.)

Still, desiring to get rid of compiler warnings is a good thing. You can reasonably address this particular one by adding the following line after you set `average`:

```
std::cout << average << '\n';
```

This assures the compiler that computing the average is not a waste of time. (Any use of the value stored in `average` would accomplish the same goal; this line is merely easy to provide.) I should note, though, that this band-aid is only for exercises. In real code, this warning usually indicates that you forgot something, and you should provide that something instead of this band-aid.